# Index of band with minimum and maximum values Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a multiband image with the bands labelled t1 to t12 representing 12 timesteps. I want to know the timestep (band) of the minimum and maximum values for each pixel and convert this timestep to an integer e.g. t7 = 7. Some timesteps have masked values.

Link to the code is here https://code.earthengine.google.com/c9e145f1be528339e1b96d03da12b3ab

Answer (score 1):

You would probably like to do something similar to this question: [Question Gianca](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307897/extracting-position-date-of-max-and-min-value-in-ndvi-time-series-in-google-eart)

For your case, this might what you want to do:

[link to Script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b14fd49d32ca5d9eccfabc2b7cdf38ca). As an example I added a 'time' band (from 1-12) and used your "median_ndvi" band. You could write a function to do this for all your bands.

Comment: The code works great for the "median_ndvi" band, but per your suggestion I'm struggling to then map this across all the bands

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to achieve this if you have an ImageCollection with each Image having two bands one being the value and the second being a constant representing the timestep.

Using the ee.Reducer.max() reducer

```
{ImageCollection}.reduce(ee.Reducer.max(2)).rename('max', 'max_t_step')
```